# Настройка flip`а галлерии по времени

Tags: jquery

```
! function(a) {
  var b = function(b, c) {
      b.data("flipped", !0);
      var e = "rotate" + b.data("axis");
      b.find(b.data("front")).css({
        transform: e + (b.data("reverse") ? "(-180deg)" : "(180deg)"),
        "z-index": "0"
      }), b.find(b.data("back")).css({
        transform: e + "(0deg)",
        "z-index": "1"
      }), b.one(d(), function() {
        a(this).trigger("flip:done"), void 0 !== c && c.call(this)
      })
    },
    c = function(b, c) {
      b.data("flipped", !1);
      var e = "rotate" + b.data("axis");
      b.find(b.data("front")).css({
        transform: e + "(0deg)",
        "z-index": "1"
      }), b.find(b.data("back")).css({
        transform: e + (b.data("reverse") ? "(180deg)" : "(-180deg)"),
        "z-index": "0"
      }), b.one(d(), function() {
        a(this).trigger("flip:done"), void 0 !== c && c.call(this)
      })
    },
    d = function() {
      var a, b = document.createElement("fakeelement"),
        c = {
          transition: "transitionend",
          OTransition: "oTransitionEnd",
          MozTransition: "transitionend",
          WebkitTransition: "webkitTransitionEnd"
        };
      for (a in c)
        if (void 0 !== b.style[a]) return c[a]
    };
  a.fn.flip = function(d, f) {
    return "function" == typeof d && (f = d), this.each(function() {
      var g = a(this);
      if (void 0 === d || "boolean" != typeof d && "string" != typeof d)
        if (g.data("initiated")) !d || void 0 === d.axis && void 0 === d.reverse || e.call(this, d, function() {
          g.trigger("flip:change"), void 0 !== f && f.call(this)
        });
        else {
          g.data("initiated", !0);
          var h = a.extend({
            axis: "y",
            reverse: !1,
            trigger: "click",
            speed: 500,
            forceHeight: !1,
            forceWidth: !1,
            autoSize: !0,
            front: "auto",
            back: "auto"
          }, d);
          "auto" == h.front ? h.front = g.find(".front").length > 0 ? ".front" : "div:first-child" : "autostrict" == h.front && (h.front = "div:first-child"), "auto" == h.back ? h.back = g.find(".back").length > 0 ? ".back" : "div:first-child + div" : "autostrict" == h.back && (h.back = "div:first-child + div"), g.data("reverse", h.reverse), g.data("axis", h.axis), g.data("front", h.front), g.data("back", h.back);
          var i = "rotate" + ("x" == h.axis.toLowerCase() ? "x" : "y"),
            j = 2 * g["outer" + ("rotatex" == i ? "Height" : "Width")]();
          g.find(g.data("back")).css({
            transform: i + "(" + (h.reverse ? "180deg" : "-180deg") + ")"
          }), g.css({
            perspective: j,
            position: "relative"
          });
          var k = h.speed / 1e3 || .5,
            l = g.find(h.front).add(h.back, g);
          if (h.forceHeight ? l.outerHeight(g.height()) : h.autoSize && l.css({
              height: "100%"
            }), h.forceWidth ? l.outerWidth(g.width()) : h.autoSize && l.css({
              width: "100%"
            }), l.css({
              "backface-visibility": "hidden",
              "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
              position: "relative",
              "z-index": "1"
            }), l.find("*").css({
              "backface-visibility": "hidden"
            }), g.find(g.data("back")).css({
              transform: i + "(" + (h.reverse ? "180deg" : "-180deg") + ")",
              "z-index": "0"
            }), (window.chrome || window.Intl && Intl.v8BreakIterator) && "CSS" in window && g.css({
              "-webkit-transform-style": "preserve-3d"
            }), setTimeout(function() {
              l.css({
                transition: "all " + k + "s ease-out"
              }), void 0 !== f && f.call(this)
            }, 20), "click" == h.trigger.toLowerCase()) g.on(a.fn.tap ? "tap.flip" : "click.flip", function(d) {
            d || (d = window.event), g.find(a(d.target).closest('button, a, input[type="submit"]')).length || (g.data("flipped") ? c(g) : b(g))
          });
          else if ("hover" == h.trigger.toLowerCase()) {
            var m = function() {
                g.off("mouseleave.flip"), b(g), setTimeout(function() {
                  g.on("mouseleave.flip", n), g.is(":hover") || c(g)
                }, h.speed + 150)
              },
              n = function() {
                c(g)
              };
            g.on("mouseenter.flip", m), g.on("mouseleave.flip", n)
          }
        }
      else "toggle" == d && (d = !g.data("flipped")), d ? b(g, f) : c(g, f)
    }), this
  };
  var e = function(b, c) {
    var d = !1;
    if (void 0 !== b.axis && a(this).data("axis") != b.axis.toLowerCase() && (a(this).data("axis", b.axis.toLowerCase()), d = !0), void 0 !== b.reverse && a(this).data("reverse") != b.reverse && (a(this).data("reverse", b.reverse), d = !0), d) {
      var e = a(this).find(a(this).data("front")).add(a(this).data("back"), a(this)),
        f = e.css(["transition-property", "transition-timing-function", "transition-duration", "transition-delay"]);
      e.css({
        transition: "none"
      });
      var g = "rotate" + a(this).data("axis");
      a(this).data("flipped") ? a(this).find(a(this).data("front")).css({
        transform: g + (a(this).data("reverse") ? "(-180deg)" : "(180deg)"),
        "z-index": "0"
      }) : a(this).find(a(this).data("back")).css({
        transform: g + "(" + (a(this).data("reverse") ? "180deg" : "-180deg") + ")",
        "z-index": "0"
      }), setTimeout(function() {
        e.css(f), c.call(this)
      }.bind(this), 0)
    } else setTimeout(c.bind(this), 0)
  }
}(jQuery);
//# sourceMappingURL=jquery.flip.min.js.map
```

---

```
<div id="card"> 
  <div class="front"> 
    Front content
  </div> 
  <div class="back">
    Back content
  </div> 
</div>
```

---

```
<script>
$("#card").flip();
</script>
```

Подскажите как сделать так чтобы флип был по времени, а не по hover и click. Желательно для каждого div рандомное время.

http://nnattawat.github.io/flip/

Comment: видимо как тут `g.on("mouseenter.flip", m), g.on("mouseleave.flip", n)` вызовите просто функции m() и n() при помощи settimeout

Comment: А можно поподробнее? Весьма посредственно знаю js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так, отметил комметарием фикс

```js
$(function() {
  ! function(a) {
    var b = function(b, c) {
        b.data("flipped", !0);
        var e = "rotate" + b.data("axis");
        b.find(b.data("front")).css({
          transform: e + (b.data("reverse") ? "(-180deg)" : "(180deg)"),
          "z-index": "0"
        }), b.find(b.data("back")).css({
          transform: e + "(0deg)",
          "z-index": "1"
        }), b.one(d(), function() {
          a(this).trigger("flip:done"), void 0 !== c && c.call(this)
        })
      },
      c = function(b, c) {
        b.data("flipped", !1);
        var e = "rotate" + b.data("axis");
        b.find(b.data("front")).css({
          transform: e + "(0deg)",
          "z-index": "1"
        }), b.find(b.data("back")).css({
          transform: e + (b.data("reverse") ? "(180deg)" : "(-180deg)"),
          "z-index": "0"
        }), b.one(d(), function() {
          a(this).trigger("flip:done"), void 0 !== c && c.call(this)
        })
      },
      d = function() {
        var a, b = document.createElement("fakeelement"),
          c = {
            transition: "transitionend",
            OTransition: "oTransitionEnd",
            MozTransition: "transitionend",
            WebkitTransition: "webkitTransitionEnd"
          };
        for (a in c)
          if (void 0 !== b.style[a]) return c[a]
      };
    a.fn.flip = function(d, f) {
      return "function" == typeof d && (f = d), this.each(function() {
        var g = a(this);
        if (void 0 === d || "boolean" != typeof d && "string" != typeof d)
          if (g.data("initiated")) !d || void 0 === d.axis && void 0 === d.reverse || e.call(this, d, function() {
            g.trigger("flip:change"), void 0 !== f && f.call(this)
          });
          else {
            g.data("initiated", !0);
            var h = a.extend({
              axis: "y",
              reverse: !1,
              trigger: "click",
              speed: 500,
              forceHeight: !1,
              forceWidth: !1,
              autoSize: !0,
              front: "auto",
              back: "auto"
            }, d);
            "auto" == h.front ? h.front = g.find(".front").length > 0 ? ".front" : "div:first-child" : "autostrict" == h.front && (h.front = "div:first-child"), "auto" == h.back ? h.back = g.find(".back").length > 0 ? ".back" : "div:first-child + div" : "autostrict" == h.back && (h.back = "div:first-child + div"), g.data("reverse", h.reverse), g.data("axis", h.axis), g.data("front", h.front), g.data("back", h.back);
            var i = "rotate" + ("x" == h.axis.toLowerCase() ? "x" : "y"),
              j = 2 * g["outer" + ("rotatex" == i ? "Height" : "Width")]();
            g.find(g.data("back")).css({
              transform: i + "(" + (h.reverse ? "180deg" : "-180deg") + ")"
            }), g.css({
              perspective: j,
              position: "relative"
            });
            var k = h.speed / 1e3 || .5,
              l = g.find(h.front).add(h.back, g);


            // вставьте интервал подобный этому
            // вставьте интервал подобный этому
            setInterval(function() {
              b(g)
            }, 2500);
            setInterval(function() {
              c(g)
            }, 5000);
            // вставьте интервал подобный этому
            // вставьте интервал подобный этому


            if (h.forceHeight ? l.outerHeight(g.height()) : h.autoSize && l.css({
              height: "100%"
            }), h.forceWidth ? l.outerWidth(g.width()) : h.autoSize && l.css({
              width: "100%"
            }), l.css({
              "backface-visibility": "hidden",
              "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
              position: "relative",
              "z-index": "1"
            }), l.find("*").css({
              "backface-visibility": "hidden"
            }), g.find(g.data("back")).css({
              transform: i + "(" + (h.reverse ? "180deg" : "-180deg") + ")",
              "z-index": "0"
            }), (window.chrome || window.Intl && Intl.v8BreakIterator) && "CSS" in window && g.css({
              "-webkit-transform-style": "preserve-3d"
            }), setTimeout(function() {
              l.css({
                transition: "all " + k + "s ease-out"
              }), void 0 !== f && f.call(this)
            }, 20), "click" == h.trigger.toLowerCase()) g.on(a.fn.tap ? "tap.flip" : "click.flip", function(d) {
              d || (d = window.event), g.find(a(d.target).closest('button, a, input[type="submit"]')).length || (g.data("flipped") ? c(g) : b(g));


            });
            else if ("hover" == h.trigger.toLowerCase()) {
              var m = function() {
                  g.off("mouseleave.flip"), b(g), setTimeout(function() {
                    g.on("mouseleave.flip", n), g.is(":hover") || c(g)
                  }, h.speed + 150)
                },
                n = function() {
                  c(g)
                };
              g.on("mouseenter.flip", m), g.on("mouseleave.flip", n);


            }
          } else "toggle" == d && (d = !g.data("flipped")), d ? b(g, f) : c(g, f)
      }), this
    };
    var e = function(b, c) {
      var d = !1;
      if (void 0 !== b.axis && a(this).data("axis") != b.axis.toLowerCase() && (a(this).data("axis", b.axis.toLowerCase()), d = !0), void 0 !== b.reverse && a(this).data("reverse") != b.reverse && (a(this).data("reverse", b.reverse), d = !0), d) {
        var e = a(this).find(a(this).data("front")).add(a(this).data("back"), a(this)),
          f = e.css(["transition-property", "transition-timing-function", "transition-duration", "transition-delay"]);
        e.css({
          transition: "none"
        });
        var g = "rotate" + a(this).data("axis");
        a(this).data("flipped") ? a(this).find(a(this).data("front")).css({
          transform: g + (a(this).data("reverse") ? "(-180deg)" : "(180deg)"),
          "z-index": "0"
        }) : a(this).find(a(this).data("back")).css({
          transform: g + "(" + (a(this).data("reverse") ? "180deg" : "-180deg") + ")",
          "z-index": "0"
        }), setTimeout(function() {
          e.css(f), c.call(this)
        }.bind(this), 0)
      } else setTimeout(c.bind(this), 0)
    };



  }(jQuery);
  //# sourceMappingURL=jquery.flip.min.js.map

  $("#card").flip({
    trigger: 'manual'
  });




});
```

```css
#card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.front,
.back {
  background-color: tomato;
}
.back {
  background-color: green;
}
#card > div {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card">
  <div class="front">
    Front content
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    Back content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, почти то что надо! Еще можно обратно чтобы флип был? UPD: А сделать рандомное время нереально (через какой нибудь math.random и min\max)? Извините что так в лоб, просто очень хочеться :) а в JS = 0

Comment: Ой! Понял! Но вопрос рандомного числа в силе.

Comment: Щас будет быдло код)) не знаю правильность написания JS но что нибудь типо такого `var random;
            random = '
function getRandomInt(1000, 3000)
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000;
}`

Comment: Все. Сделал сам. Но спасибо большое за "путь истинный"